# Shopping Cart Rule to discount N 'paired' items

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I'm interested in creating a shopping cart rule that offers a discounted item B for ever item A purchased.

So, if someone purchase 5 of item A they get 30% off of 5 of item B.  But iif they have more than 5 of item B the balance of item B are full price.

I suppose there is also an  alternative approach to create product alternatives that bundle item B with item A.

Clarificatoin:  The question is asking about 'N' paired items, 5 is just an example.   I want there to be a disocunt only want 1 of ItemB for discounted for every 1 of ItemA purchased. This might be 2 of each, 5 of each, or 10 of each.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you accomplish what you are describing.

First, set up a Shopping Cart Price Rule.  Customize it with the options below.  I used "productA" and "productB" as example skus.  Just replace those with your's.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how this example solves my scenario, or why it has a qty of 5 hardcoded in the rules.  My Scenario:  

_If cart contains 2 qty ProductA and 4 qty ProductB they get discount on only 2 of the ProductB._

_If they purchase 4 of ProductA and 2 qty of ProductB they only get a disocunt on 2 of ProductB._

Comment: I was basing it on your question: "So, if someone purchase 5 of item A they get 30% off of 5 of item B. But iif they have more than 5 of item B the balance of item B are full price."

Comment: I'll adjust it to see if I can find the right combination of rules.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to do it for a exact # of items.  The challenge I'm trying to solve is supporting this paired discount on an arbitrary # of paired products.